# Переход с IPv4 на IPv6, почему хорошо, почему плохо?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

Хочу обсудить с участниками, переход с IPv4, на IPv6. Насколько быстро все перейдут? (хотя вроде полностью и не собираются). Чем это хорошо, чем плохо. С одной стороны отлично, что у каждого будет свой уникальный IP адрес, а с другой стороны ужасно. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Да уже лет 20 переходят 

Comment: @AlexeyTen соглашусь, вот я и думаю, кому выгодно переходить, кому нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В какой-то момент (возможно, не так скоро) глобальные адреса IPv4 могут закончиться, и некоторые ресурсы будут иметь только адрес IPv6.

Если вы разрабатываете сетевую программу, вполне допускаю, что в некоторых жестко нормированных сферах (медицина, оборона) может появиться требование поддержки IPv6, и тогда пограмму без IPv6 просто нельзя будет продать. В более свободных, не стандартизированных сферах, программа без IPv6 сигнализирует, скажем так, о недостаточном профессионализме ее разработчиков. Чисто с рыночной точки зрения, лучше такую поддержку иметь.

Если вы разрабатываете сетевое устройство, предназначенное для прямого подключения к компьютеру (максимум, через LAN), поддерживать только IPv4 пока еще, насколько я вижу, нормально и общепринято. Если работаете с IoT - лучше поддерживать оба протокола.

Comment: Ответ получился несколько философский, не 100% технический. Так же, впрочем, как и вопрос. Я бы предпочел отправить его как комментарий, но он слишком длинный.